# A short bio of me, guess what I am or I'll end up in the sea

Tags: riddle

1. My mother died giving me birth at an old age.
2. I was surrounded by romantics as much as pragmatics.
3. People still judge me on my skin color.
4. I have two enemies but a very good friend, who has matured more than me.
5. I am just not aging well but I am fortunate enough to have at least a place in this dirty world.
6. I appeal to drug addicts as well as artsy intellectuals.
7. I am the weakest and yet I can harm you
8. Bureaucrats love me

Comment: Do you mean bureaucrats? or do I get to learn a new word today?

Comment: Right sorry! English is not my primary language :)

Comment: No worries! I never know for sure. And props. I couldn't communicate in any other language

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you:

> Paper

1. My mother died giving me birth at an old age.

   > The tree died when it was old enough to be cut down to make paper.
2. I was surrounded by romantics as much as pragmatics.

   > Paper can have love letters and romantic stories, or calculations, logic, and knowledge on it.
3. People still judge me on my skin color.

   > Paper is usually white, some people want different coloured paper (?). Edit - Skin colour could be referring to what is actually on the 'skin' of the paper, the words/drawings etc.
4. I have two enemies but a very good friend, who has matured more than me.

   > Rock paper scissors comes to mind, not too sure about this one. Is the friend a pencil?
5. I am just not aging well but I am fortunate enough to have at least a place in this dirty world.

   > Paper is being outdated by the digital world, but we will always use it. Paper is clean when compared to the dirty world (?) Edit - Thanks to @Belhenix, this could be referring to using paper tissues and napkins to clean things.
6. I appeal to drug addicts as well as artsy intellectuals.

   > People roll joints with paper (?) and also do art on it.
7. I am the weakest and yet I can harm you

   > Paper is weak but paper cuts hurt.
8. Bureaucrats love me

   > Bureaucrats work with paper and documents.

Title. A short bio of me, guess what I am or I'll end up in the sea

> Not sure on this one

Thanks for the cool riddle.

Comment: for the "dirty world" part, maybe [rot13](https://rot13.com/)(vg ersref gb hfvat gvffhrf naq ancxvaf gb pyrna guvatf? barfrys vapyhqrq bs pbhefr)

Comment: Totally nailed it! The judgement on color can be applied as well to money (dollar papers etc..)

Comment: Ah yes I see now. How did the title play into it?

Answer (score 2):

Could you be

> CHALK?

Title: *guess what I am or I'll end up in the sea*

> Chalk cliffs decay into the sea.

1. My mother died giving me birth at an old age.

   > Chalk is formed from the shells of ancient living beings?
2. I was surrounded by romantics as much as pragmatics.

   > Not sure about this.
3. People still judge me on my skin color.

   > It's white, and often used for that purpose. **White** Cliffs of Dover (not Chalk Cliffs of Dover). Also can come in other colours.
4. I have two enemies but a very good friend, who has matured more than me.

   > Maybe the friend is limestone? Or gypsum?
5. I am just not aging well but I am fortunate enough to have at least a place in this dirty world.

   > Chalk is less popular now, what with whiteboards and markers, but it's still used for blackboards.
6. I appeal to drug addicts as well as artsy intellectuals.

   > Chalk can be used in art. Probably it can be abused by drug addicts too.
7. I am the weakest and yet I can harm you

   > It's the weakest on the Mohs scale, but chalk dust can be harmful.

Comment: Cool! Close, but there's something that fits better :p

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> **crude oil**?

*My mother died giving me birth at an old age.*

> Oil that is formed from flora and fauna compressed over time

*I was surrounded by romantics as much as pragmatics.*

> Not too sure, but before becoming oil its constituents were surrounded by all sorts of people

*People still judge me on my skin color.*

> The colour of oil determines its quality

*I have two enemies but a very good friend, who has matured more than me.*

> Fire could consume it and water doesn’t mix with it, hence they could be considered enemies. Petrol is refined from oil, so it could be considered as a matured friend.

*I am just not aging well but I am fortunate enough to have at least a place in this dirty world.*

> Technically, oil doesn’t age at all, unless it’s used in some way. Oil is also a contributor to pollution.

*I appeal to drug addicts as well as artsy intellectuals.*

> Crude oil can be used to make drugs ([example](https://www.atmosi.com/en/news-events/blogs/cocaine-is-a-crude-oil-high/)). It can be also used to make oil paints for artistry.

*I am the weakest and yet I can harm you*

> Oil is weaker than other forms of hazards but it still harmful in its crude form.

*Bureaucrats love me*

> This could relate to the political strife around oil.